# Testing equality of relative frequency ratio in binomial sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

I am sorry if this question is too basic or was somewhere else here on Cr-Validated, but i didn't find anything suitable.

I study patients with cancer who were made a byopsy taking to test presence of cancer cellcs 12 prostate core samples. When core samples are explored, they are divided into two groups whether there was found  1-2 prostatic intraepithelial neoplasia samples or 3-4 prostatic intraepithelial neoplasia samples (or PIN samples). I want to test the hypothesis that cancer detectability ( 0 states for no cancer cells found and 1 states for presence of cancer cells) is higher among patients with 3-4 PIN samples rather than 1-2.

To visualise - this is how sample could look like

```
PIN Group Cancer
1   I     0
2   I     0
1   I     1
...
4   II    1
3   II    1
4   II    0
....
```

Mathematically speaking I have to test hypothesis of  relative frequency ratio equality. How do I do that?

Simultaneously I opened two sources - one asserting that I have to calculate two CI for ratios and if they intersect then it means that ratios can be equal, and other source claiming it is wrong method.

What do you think? I will be eternally grateful for any clarifications!